# How can I connect my old iPad 2 to WiFi?

Tags: ios, ipad, network, wifi, web-browser

The back of my iPad says `A1395` 16 GB, which means it's the iPad 2 (Wi-Fi) from 2011 according to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201471). It's running iOS 9.1 (`13B143`). "About" says `Model FC979LL/A`.

I can no longer connect to WiFi, so that means I can't connect to the internet.

I've tried a complete factory reset multiple times.

This iPad shouldn't be trash! It's a nice thin touchscreen device that I want to make use of somehow!

E.g. I want to use it as a digital photo frame looping through images on my local WiFi network.

If I'm willing to do pretty much anything to this iPad at this point (jailbreak, roll back to previous iOS, or install a different operating system entirely, etc.), what can I do so that I can enable this to browse my website hosted within my local network?

My WiFi router is a NOKIA `BGW320-505` (AT&T fiber) with WPA-2, WPA-3,
and B/G/N/AX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

make sure your router is running in WPA2 or WPA2/WPA3 Transitional mode. Your ipad is not compatible with WPA3, so needs WPA2.  I have seen comments that the Transitional mode can cause issues, so perhaps set it to WPA2 and see if the ipad connects then.

Comment: NOKIA BGW320-505 (AT&T fiber) gives me 3 options in the dropdown for WPA Version: WPA-1 and WPA-2, WPA-2, WPA-2 and WPA-3. It has been on WPA-2 and WPA-3. Just now I changed it to WPA-2.

Comment: Holy smokes! This worked! I could have _sworn_ I'd already tried this! I then tried to visit apple.stackexchange.com as a test. Weirdly, the https isn't working. It said "Your connection is not private", and I needed to click Advanced > "Proceed to apple.stackexchange.com (unsafe)". And then when that loaded, all the CSS styles were missing. It was just basic HTML (with lists, bold, font size, etc). And my own React app site showed just a blank page. But you totally answered the question about how to get back onto the wifi network! Thanks!

Comment: It makes me wonder if the old Apple TV that hasn't been connecting might connect now too…

Comment: The https issues are probably related to root certificate expiration. Old operating systems won't know about the newer root certificates used to sign recent https webpage certificates. I don't know if there's a way around this on your specific device. We live in a world where it's legal for hardware makers to sell devices and later render them useless.

Comment: @Ryan Related to what Glenn Willen said, I believe Firefox usually bundles its own certificates, so if you can install a recent version of Firefox, you *might* be able to get https working in that browser. However, given Apple's monopoly on browser engines on iOS, I don't know if the Firefox for iOS actually uses its own certificates, or if it just relies on the ones bundled with the OS like Safari.

Comment: Thanks, Glenn and @8bittree.

Comment: I haven't tried this with an iPad - but if you can't update all your certificates I have worked around a similar problem (with a non Apple device) by using a MITM proxy. You need to be able to get the iPad to trust a self signed certificate and you need another device (e.g. a UNIX box of some sort) to run a proxy (and it will need to have up-to-date certificates). That allows you to continue using the iPad as a client. It's a hack but in case it helps...

Answer (score 2):

Just some pointers - not exactly sure about the menus in iOS 9, but it should be along those lines.

- Can other devices connect to your router?
- Have you checked that Airplane Mode is off and Wi-Fi Mode is on?
- Is "Ask to Join Networks" set to On?
- Have you tried off-on toggling Wi-Fi?
- Have you tried renewing the DHCP lease?
- Maybe reboot the device.
- If this didn't help, restart the router
- Try 'Forget this Network', then reconnect by selecting your network from the list
- Have you tried resetting your network settings by going to Settings >
  General > Reset Network Settings.

Finally, if you have an Apple Store nearby, try booking an appointment with them and ask a Genius.

[image: iOS 9 screen] not my screenshot, just something I found online to help with orientation.

[image: network reset]